# calling a nodejs express REST service with &amp; into url

Tags: node.js, express, ampersand

having built an express REST api got a problem when one of the clients is calling one service with encoding the & to & a m p ; --without spaces :)

I do not know how to modify all the request object's properties before is routed.

I tried in a middleware to modify the req.query object but the req.query keys itself are "corrupted":

ex: 'amp;paramname' because express it is splitting it at & from & a m p;

Comment: Can you show code and URLS you are hitting and result?

Comment: Call ex.: https://localhost:8080/rs?p1=v1&amp;p2=v2&amp;  
then req.query is:  
<!-- language: lang-js -->  
    { p1: 'v1',  
    'amp;p2': 'v2',  
    'amp;p3': ... }

Comment: and app.js:  
    var express    = require('express');  
    var app = module.exports = express();    
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');  
    var validator = require('express-validator');  
    var cors = require('cors');  
    app.use( bodyParser.json() );  
    app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }) );  
    app.use( validator() );  
    app.use( cors() );  
    // START THE SERVER  
    // ====================  
    if(!module.parent){ app.listen(config.port); }  
    // REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------  
    app.use('/rs', require('./routes/rsRoutes'));

Comment: I cannot get the formatting on this nice, I put the question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/E37HWErCMWg) also, where it works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that indeed the client call is bad and anyway is not an easy way to "fix it" so that's it.